# missing required keys: [:option]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have this routes which :vote is initiated by default

```
match "poems/by_vote" => "poems#index" , via: [:get] , :as => :poems_by_votes , :vote => true
```

when I use:

```
<%= link_to "by_vote" , poems_by_votes_path%>
```

I confront with:

```
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"poems", :vote=>true} missing required keys: [:option]
```

I also used these but none of them worked:

```
<%= link_to "test" , poems_by_votes_path(:vote => true)%>
<%= link_to "test" , poems_by_votes_path , :options => { :vote => true } %>
<%= link_to "test" , poems_by_votes_path(true)%>
```

what to do?

Comment: Is this route inside of a `namespace` `scope` or other some kind of other block?

Comment: no it is not in any block.

Comment: Also, what URL are you expecting this to generate? `/poems/by_vote?vote=true`?

Comment: /poems/by_vote ( which is matched to index method and in the passed parameters we can see :vote )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`poems_by_votes_path` is just going to return a string that then is going to be used by link_to. The `vote` parameter needs to be included somewhere in that string (such as in the query string). I would do something like:

```
get 'poems/by_vote', as: :poems_by_vote

....

poems_by_vote_path # poems/by_vote
poems_by_vote_path(vote: true) # poems/by_vote?vote=true

....

def index
  vote = params[:vote] || false
  # look up poems based on vote...
end
```

Comment: yeah it works and tnx. but isn't there any other way to avoid something like ?vote=true  ? I want to have poems/by_vote and nothing more.